# Can I modify the vector mutiplied by a matrix to have specific resultant vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonlinear-system

Given a matrix $W$ and a vector $d$ where $W*d = g$.  the dimension of $W$ is $n$x$n$ and of $d$ and $g$ is $n$x$1$.

Assume the $W$ is known and half of the vector $d$ is known too,  my question is,  can I set the other half of the vector $d$ to have the resultant of multiplication $g$ known ?

That can be summarized as below :

[image]

what I known is $k_{n/2 + 1 } ... k_n$ , The question that I set that part of the vector in order to have the resultant vector $g$ known ?

**EDIT**

Following the solution in the answer below, I have built the matlab code and used Gaussien elimination to solve $k$, but when I multiply the matrix again $W*[d;k]$ I can't get the same value of $g$. here is the code

```
close all
clc
W = hadamard(8);  %Taking the matrix of hadamard as matrix W
W1 = W(:,1:4); 
W2 = W(:,5:8); 
g = ones(8,1); 
d = [0.7000 + 0.7000i; 0.7000 - 0.7000i; -0.7000 - 0.7000i; -0.7000 - 0.7000i]; 

A = W2; 
b = g - W1*d; 

n= size(A,2);
k= zeros(n,1);   %initialize x
%code for forward elimination to correct the matrix A to upper triangular
%form
for i =1: n-1
    m=A(i+1:n,i)/A(i,i);
    A(i+1:n,:)=A(i+1:n,:)-m*A(i,:);
    b(i+1:n,:) = b(i+1:n,:)-m*b(i,:);
end

%code for back substitution to find unknowns
k(n,:)= b(n,:)/A(n,n);
for i= n-1:-1:1
    k(i,:) =(b(i,:)- A(i,i+1:n)*k(i+1:n,:))/A(i,i);
end
D = [d;k]; 

W*D       %% that should be equal to g !!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}W_1 & W_2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}d \\ k\end{bmatrix}=g$$

$$W_1 d + W_2k = g$$

$$W_1 d = g-W_2k$$

Now you can solve a linear system for $d$ if it is consistent.

Edit:

For your code, if you check the RREF of $[A, b]$, you will notice that it is not a consistent system.

In particular, hadamard matrix is invertible, hence if we solve $WD=g$ $D$ is unique. If you choose the first few component of $D$ arbirarily, it need not be consistent.

Comment: you mean in that case, we will set the vector $k$, right?  so:  $k = W_2^{-1}g - W_2^{-1}W_1d$,  in that case the matrix $W_2$ cannot be inversed as it's not square.

Comment: From your description $k$ is known. you can for example, use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Yes, $d$ is not known, and $k$ is known and I should set $k$ to have the result of multiplication $W*[d;k] = g$.  as I understood from your response that you set $d$ instead of $k$. could you please explain more. I couldn't get what you meant by your answer.

Comment: The problem is now of the form of $Ax=b$ right where $A$ is rectangular, we just have to solve the lienar system right since $W_1$ and $g-W_2k$ are known right.

Comment: OK .. thank you so much, I will check it and let you know.

Comment: $W_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times \frac{n}2}$, $d \in \mathbb{R}^\frac{n}2$

Comment: I did that by matlab, but I still can't get the same value of $g$ I mean after multiplication of $W$ and the found vector which include $[d;k]$. I added the matlab code into the question.